# Yii check scenario in beforeSave()

Tags: yii, behavior, scenarios, before-save

For one action I need transform $album_id before save it to DB
in model function beforeSave() i do:

```
// преобразовать album -> album_id
$album_id=array();
foreach($this->string2array($this->album, '\|') as $one)
    $album_id[]=Album::model()->findByAttributes(array('album' => $one))->id;

$this->album_id = $this->array2string($album_id);
```

but for another action I don't need this transform, because $album_id is already in proper state. So I set scenario 'batchcreate' in that action:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    Yii::import('ext.multimodelform.MultiModelForm');

    $model = new Album('create'); 

    $song = new Song();
    $song->setScenario('batchcreate');
    ...
}
```

and try to check this scenario in model:

```
if(!($this->scenario === 'batchcreate')) {
    // преобразовать album -> album_id
    $album_id=array();
    foreach($this->string2array($this->album, '\|') as $one)
        $album_id[]=Album::model()->findByAttributes(array('album' => $one))->id;
    $this->album_id = $this->array2string($album_id);
}
```

but the condition is always true. Why my scenario doesn't set or doesn't check in if statement?
Or maybe it's better to check not scenario, but make another variable, so how to set its value for 2 different cases?

my whole beforeSave():

```
protected function beforeSave()
    {
        if(parent::beforeSave())
        {

            // преобразовать whoes -> who
            $who=array();
            foreach($this->string2array($this->whoes) as $one) {
                $userrow = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username' => $one));
                if($userrow) $who[]=CHtml::encode($userrow->id);
                else $who[]=$one;                              
            }
            $this->who = $this->array2string($who); 


            //var_dump( $this->scenario );
            if(!($this->scenario == 'batchcreate')) {
            //if($this->notbatchcreate == 'yes') {
                // преобразовать album -> album_id
                $album_id=array();
                foreach($this->string2array($this->album, '\|') as $one)
                    $album_id[]=Album::model()->findByAttributes(array('album' => $one))->id;
                $this->album_id = $this->array2string($album_id);
            }



            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: What is the base class of Album and Song?

Comment: class Song extends ActiveRecord; class Album extends ActiveRecord

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump( $this->scenario )? Where do you perform this check? What method of your model?

Comment: i perform this check in model in protected function beforeSave(); Valentin, i make variable instead scenario and check it - if($this->notbatchcreate == 'yes'), in one controller action i set it as $model->notbatchcreate = 'yes'; but in another not. So it works. But why scenario doesn't work i can't understand

Comment: hm! var_dump( $this->scenario ) shows: string(6) "insert", and with if(!($this->scenario == 'insert')) it works too, but i set scenario = 'batchcreate', why it is 'insert'?

Comment: 'insert' is the default scenario set in CActiveRecord's constructor. It's hard to say what's wrong looking on the tiny snippet of code in your question.

Comment: @almix could you include the whole `beforeSave` function?

Comment: added code of beforeSave function

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$song = new Song();
$song->setScenario('batchcreate');
```

you can simply do

```
$song = new Song('batchcreate');
```

In `beforeSave()`

```
if ( $this->scenario != 'batchcreate' ) {
    echo "good - scenario is not batchcreate";
    die();
}
echo 'nope...';
var_dump($this->scenario);
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch the order: call `parent::beforeSave()` after your code for checking the scenario. The inherited method `beforeSave()` may be altering your scenario.